# Phonegap Android Application - loading always wrong data icon in dynamically generated <li>

Tags: android, jquery, css, cordova

I was trying to create a li dynamically with JSON response and have included data-icon "check" in that. But in result its always displaying "arrow-r" data-icon.

Generation of li :-

```
function CallvarURL(url) {
    var respPrice ;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type : "GET",
        dataType : "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        async : false,
        success : function(msg) {
            respPrice = msg;
            $("#varList li").remove();
            $.each(respPrice.Value, function(index, value) {
                if(value.SubVar_id == 'NoDataFound' ) {
                    alert('No product is assigned to '+ localStorage.getItem('userId') +  ' for update the price please contact your admin.');
                } else {                        
                    vari = value.SrNo;
                    commVari = value.subVar_eng_name;
                    minPrice = value.Frm_price;
                    maxPrice = value.to_price;
                    var update = value.TimeCheck;
                    if (update == 'Y') {
                        $respPrice = '<li data-categoryId = "'+ vari +'" data-categoryId2 = "'+ minPrice +'" data-categoryId3 = "'+ maxPrice +'" data-categoryId4 = "'+ commVari +'"><a href="#" data-icon="star"><b class="stuff">' + commVari + '</b><br><b class="tcolour">' + minPrice + ' - ' + maxPrice + '</b></a></li>';
                    } else {
                        $respPrice = '<li data-categoryId = "'+ vari +'" data-categoryId2 = "'+ minPrice +'" data-categoryId3 = "'+ maxPrice +'" data-categoryId4 = "'+ commVari +'"><b class="stuff">' + commVari + '</b><br><b class="tcolour">' + minPrice + ' - ' + maxPrice + '</b></li>';
                        }
                     $('#varList').append($respPrice);  
                    };
                });
```

[image]

Can't find the reason of that ? I have tried other values for data-icon also but its always displaying "arrow-r". Any help..??

Comment: post some script as well, jquery/javascript

Comment: Have updated the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi as I understood you are using jquery mobile. So here I am giving you link for jsfiddle in which I have created list with checkbox. You are getting right arrow in your code because you are giving it in  tag. Jquerymobile by default gives right arrow in  tag.

Just visit this jsfiddle (jsfiddle.net/4FdcY/366/) Hope it will help you.